# Dell PowerEdge t710 virtualization suggestions

Tags: virtualization, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, domain-controller, dell-poweredge

My company just bought a dell PowerEdge t710 server with 48 gig ram 4tb disk 4x4 gb ethernet ports. My job is to configure virtual (hyperV) system infrastructure on this server.
The requirements are:
1) Domain controller
2) file server
3) microsoft exhchage server
4) intranet server - shareponint
5) Development server (SVN and SQL server 2008)

My first thought was to have the Domain Controller as first OS of the server and then using hyper v to install other servers, but i dont agree with it cause Domain Controller gets updates and needs to restart it is gonna pause all other member servers.
I also thought that a Windows server 2008 Standard edition must be installed as OS of the server and after that install other servers or services via hyperv

Please can you suggest with some configuration. Is there any issue having a domain controller as virtual server? Or if some of you guys can tell me how to plan this infrastructure.

Sorry if i was complicated but please try too understand me cause i am new at system integration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You really want to consider having an additional DC on bare metal. For your actual hypervisor you might consider running Hyper-V Server 2008r2 or you will have approx 16gb of RAM thats unusable.

Here is what I would be doing:

PowerEdge t710:

Hyper-V Server 2008r2 for the host OS

VM1 - File Server
VM2 - Exchange
VM3 - Intranet/Sharepoint
VM4 - SVN/SQL
VM5 - Additional DC

Then I'd buy something relatively low end to be an additional DC, you dont need a lot of horsepower if its just going to be a DC so you could probably get by with about $1500 hardware costs.

Doing it this way you can perform maintenance on either of your DCs and still be able to maintain all your services.

Comment: I agree.  Running critical services on the Hyper-V Host Server is a **Bad Idea.**

Comment: Worth noting why you want that bare metal DC: so the H-V host has something to provide authentication, DNS, ... when it starts.

Comment: Ok so I will have a DC on another cheap server (the old one) and go with your suggestion also i am thinking to add another dc on hyperv just to have it as backup and to replicate it with dc1